# zsh themes loaded but not working

Tags: terminal, iterm, themes, zsh

I set theme in `.zshrc` file:

```
ZSH_THEME="random"
```

And when open new tab, it shows that new theme is loaded:

```
[oh-my-zsh] Random theme '/Users/maks/.oh-my-zsh/themes/gozilla.zsh-theme' loaded...
mac
```

But in fact I dont see any changes in theme.

New tab again

```
[oh-my-zsh] Random theme '/Users/maks/.oh-my-zsh/themes/crunch.zsh-theme' loaded
```

and again:

```
[oh-my-zsh] Random theme '/Users/maks/.oh-my-zsh/themes/tjkirch.zsh-theme' loaded...
```

But still see the same theme. I have already reloaded mac, but no result. The same result in `Terminal` and `iTerm`

**Update:**

Not all themes fails. This one works: `trapd00r` but with error: `prompt_jnrowe_precmd:3: command not found: zsh_path`. Others not working.

**Update 2:** 
`linuxonly` theme works too:

```
[oh-my-zsh] Random theme '/Users/maks/.oh-my-zsh/themes/linuxonly.zsh-theme' loaded...
mac
maks@Makss-Mac:s047->/Users/maks (0)
```

but with error:

```
Can't open perl script "/home/scp1/bin/foopath": No such file or directory
```

Comment: No it dont work if I choose theme manually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have a custom PS1 that is overriding the prompt from the theme you have selected?

1. Check you don't have any additional lines in ~/.zshrc beyond the default?

   1. Backup your .zshrc
   2. Delete all lines beyond `export PATH=$PATH:/`…
   3. Reload your Terminal
2. Do you have any plugins that are messing with things?

   - Check ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/ for any additional plugins.
   - Remove all your plugins from your ~/.zshrc and reload your Terminal.
3. Check you don't have any additional lines in your ~/.zprofile?

   ```
   mv ~/.zprofile ~/.zprofile-bak
   ```

   …and reload your Terminal. (Put back with `mv ~/.zprofile-bak ~/.zprofile`)

<sup>Note: `trapd00r` and `linuxonly` show the same errors for me</sup>

Comment: I Deleted all lines beyond line `export PATH=$PATH:/` and themes started to work.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have your iTerm profile set to report 256 colors?

[image]

Comment: `Report Terminal Type` was `xterm`, now `xterm-256color`. But theme still is not working.

Comment: +1 to counter undeserved no-comment downvote - this is a viable reason why the themes may not appear to work for some people.

Comment: I don't use iTerm, I use the normal Terminal app. But this fixed it for me: Terminal (menu, top left) > Preferences > Profiles (tab) > (gear icon bottom left) > Restore Default Profiles